# Creating circle from data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data and what i am trying to do is to make full circle and half circle using that data. Below is the code i did so far but it should start from zero and end at zero. Also this creates a so called half circle. Is there a way to create half-circle and full-circle, starts from zero and ends at zero. Or using the data without manipulating it?

```
np.random.seed(15)
data = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)
print(data)
arr = data - np.mean(data)
arr = np.cumsum(np.sort(arr))
plt.plot(arr)
plt.axhline(0, color="#000000", ls="-.", linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()

[72 12  5  0 28 27 71 75 85 47 93 17 31 23 32 62 10 15 68 39 37 19 44 77
 60 29 79 15 56 49  1 31 96 85 26 34 75 50 65 53 70 41 34 40 22 63 79 56
 28 99  4  7 66 42 96  7 24 60 45 83 49 53 29 76 88 76 33  2 88 42 81 51
 62 23 93 98 87 18 90 90 16 77 90 32 70  4 28 84 35 28 69 54 64 73 84 56
 46 38 35 14]
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I already did that

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Circle](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html) (http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
c = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=1, edgecolor='b', facecolor='None')
ax.add_patch(c)
plt.show()
```

Comment: i need to use my own data and also print the circle data